# why ' and " behaving differenlty in php

Tags: php, echo

```
echo '\n....'.$_SESSION['count'].' rows inserted.........................\n';
no new line using this

echo "\n....".$_SESSION['count']." rows inserted.........................\n";
gives new line with this
```

why ' and " behaving differenlty

Comment: This is covered in the basic PHP documentation about strings - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - please read the manual before coming here asking such basic questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'` is for literals. `"` is for parsed text.

See the [PHP Manual Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape
>   sequences for special characters **will not be expanded when they occur
>   in single quoted strings.**